# Next is not defined next(err)

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = require('path');
    var walk = require('walk');
    var xml2js = require('xml2js');

    var jsonDir ;
    var convertXml = function (xml_dir, json_dir) {
        jsonDir =  json_dir;

        var walker = walk.walk(xml_dir, { followLinks: true });
        walker.on("errors", fDirWalkError);
        walker.on("end", fDirWalkEnd);
        walker.on("file", fDirWalkFile);

    }

    function fDirWalkError (err) {
        console.log ("fDirWalkError: " + err);
        next (err);
    }

    function fDirWalkEnd  () {
        console.log ("======= End of directory walk");
    }

    function fDirWalkFile (root, fileStat, next) {
        if (fileStat.name.indexOf(".xml") < 0) {
            console.log ("skipping file " + fileStat.name + " (does not end in .xml)");
            return;
        } else {
            var xml_file = path.resolve(root, fileStat.name);
            console.log ("xml file: " + xml_file);

            fs.readFile('xml_file', function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log ("error reading file:" + xml_file);
                    next (err);
                }
                xml2js.parseString (data, function (err, json_obj) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log (err);
                        next (err);
                    }
                    var json_string = JSON.stringify(json_obj, null, 2);
                    var json_file = path.resolve (jsonDir, path.basename(xml_file).replace(/\.xml$/, ".json"));
                    console.log ("json file: ", json_file);

                    fs.writeFile(json_file, json_string, "utf8", function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log ("error converting yin (%s) to json(%s)", xml_file, json_file);
                            next (new Error ("error converting xml(" + xml_file + ") to json(" + json_file + ")"));
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log ("Converted xml (%s) to json(%s)", xml_file, json_file);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }
        next ();
    }

module.exports.convertXml = convertXml;




var path = require ('path'); 
var xml2js = require ('./xml2js');
console.log ("__dirname: " + __dirname); 
var templateDir = path.resolve (__dirname); 
var xmlDir = path.resolve (templateDir, "xml");
var jsonDir = path.resolve (templateDir, "jsons"); 
console.log( templateDir); 
xml2js.convertXml (xmlDir, jsonDir)
```

> /Users//Documents/GitHub//xml2js.js:19
>           next (err);
>           ^
>
> ReferenceError: next is not defined
>       at Walker.fDirWalkError (/Users//Documents/GitHub//xml2js.js:19:9)
>       at Walker.emit (events.js:321:20)
>       at Walker._wPostFilesHandler (/UsersDocuments/GitHub//node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:134:10)
>       at /Users//Documents/GitHub//node_modules/foreachasync/forEachAsync.js:15:16
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Walker.next [as _wCurFileCallback] (/Users//Documents/GitHub/node_modules/foreachasync/forEachAsync.js:14:15)
>       at Walker._wLstatHandler (/Users//Documents/GitHub//node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:84:10)
>       at /Users//Documents/GitHub//node_modules/walk/lib/walk.js:106:12

Comment: The function `next` you're trying to call comes from an Express request handler.  If you want to use it, your code has to either be directly inside a request handler so the `next` argument to that request handler is in scope or you will have to pass that `next` to any other function that wants to use it.  Since you show no request handlers in your code, it's unclear where you expect `next` to come from.

Comment: var path = require ('path');
var xml2js = require ('./xml2js');

console.log ("__dirname: " + __dirname);
var templateDir = path.resolve (__dirname);
var xmlDir = path.resolve (templateDir, "xml");
var jsonDir = path.resolve (templateDir, "jsons");
console.log( templateDir);
xml2js.convertXml (xmlDir, jsonDir); ........this is the main.js which is calling this file.

Comment: Multi-line code in comments is not readable.  If that's something you want people who read your question to see, then use the "edit" link to edit your question and add it to the question.

Comment: made those required changes

Answer (score 1):

depends on the walk documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/walk

the next param is the third param that the event send

in your case you are using

```
function fDirWalkError (err) {
    console.log ("fDirWalkError: " + err);
    next (err);
}
```

but you didnt get next function from the module in your function args

try to put it in your handler args

like this

```
function fDirWalkError (err, nodeStatsArray, next) {
    console.log ("fDirWalkError: " + err);
    next (err);
}
```

it should work

Comment: i did try but it didnt work.Basically i am just trying to convert a xml file from a folder and convert it into json and save it in the same folder